# Polling on a folder

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm working on creating a auto polling on a folder, my routes are set up in spring XML file, how can I keep the app running and polling on that folder, I was able to do that using the normal routing where they are entered in the java as from to, but now since using XML route spring, I'm not able to create a route builder or add a one.
My main is

```
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class FileTransferinSpring {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Main main = new Main();


        //main.addRouteBuilder(new //ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("MySpring.xml"));//this is now working
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "MySpring.xml");

        //ctx.start();
        System.out.println("Entered>>>>>");
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
        //ctx.stop();
    }
```

here is my config file.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd          
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route>
            <from uri="file:input?fileName=Hello.txt&amp;noop=true" />
            <to uri="file:output" />
        </route>

        <route>
            <from uri="file:input?fileName=Hello2.txt&amp;noop=true" />
            <to uri="file:output" />
        </route>


    </camelContext>

</beans>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  this: *how can I keep the app running and polling on that folder* ?

Comment: I want to have the app running on it's own and monitoring the location when ever a file.csv for example is saved in that location it will pick it and move it to the final destination, I used pollEnrich in the normal java code and did add route builder in the main and it was working but the new config I'm using camel spring and xml file with the routes, do you have any knowledge in this case?

Comment: If you specify the file name then it will not keep running. YOu should specifx the folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***FileSystemWatcher*** from Spring for monitoring file and folder changes.

For code example follow [this](https://programtalk.com/java-api-usage-examples/org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher/) link.

**FileSystemWatcher** -- [Java doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/devtools/filewatch/FileSystemWatcher.html).

But as suggested in comments, you don't need spring based solution, you can use pure Java or Apache libraries for this.

If you want to see Java or Apache library for solution, follow below examples:

1. [Apache Library for File/Folder monitoring](http://www.baeldung.com/java-watchservice-vs-apache-commons-io-monitor-library).
2. [Java Solution for File/Folder monitoring.](https://kodejava.org/how-to-monitor-file-or-directory-changes/)

Comment: I'm using dependency camel-spring for my routes and will be monitoring FTP folders for a csv file , processing that file and then sending the initial copy to be archived in a History folder on the ftp, note that I'm monitory multiple ftp servers for this csv file, All my routes in an xml file that is above...I hope this clarifies my way of coding, I able to do the polling using routebuilder like below but all my routes where in a java now they are in xml file I was trying to do the same

Comment: package com.fefodist.launcher;

import com.fefodist.routes.jdbc.DBPostgresRoute;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class AppLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new DBPostgresRoute());

        System.out.println("Starting of polling on FEFO Folder(s)");

        try {
            main.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you converting your work from Camel (java way) to Camel (spring way)? Your main method doesn't seems to be complete to let it auto run, set the CamelContext(s) to your main object to complete it.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    Main main = new Main();

    AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "MySpring.xml");

    main.setApplicationContext(ctx);
    main.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for below solution.

```
@Component
public class FileRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file://{{dir.in}}?readLock=changed&include=.*.csv"&preMove={{dir.progress}}&move={{dir.out}}&moveFailed={{dir.error}}").setId("Poller");
    }
}
```

- dir.in -Source directory for file polling
- dir.progress -File will be moved from in to progress for processing
- dir.out -File will be moved here when processed successfully
- dir.error - File moved here when any error occur during process
- readLock=changed - this will lock the file while reading
- include - this will read only csv files in source dir i.e in folder

Please note that, if you are not using preMove then default .camel folder will be created in the 'in' folder and one copy of file moved to .camel folder.

So i suggest you to use the preMove in the route.